# Test wired headset detection via software

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, adb, headphone-jack

Since I still don't know whether [my problem (call audio doesn't work without headset or speakerphone)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/124491/18559) is caused by faulty hardware or by software, I'd like to know the following:

Is there a way to tell if the headset switch in the headset jack (which tells the phone app whether a wired headset is connected or not) is working as expected?

I am looking for a solution that doesn't require disassembling the phone before knowing what is actually causing the aforementioned problem. The following idea comes to mind:

Is there a way to display/query/dump the status of the headset detection via [adb](/questions/tagged/adb)? Maybe something under `/dev`?

Or are there other ways to tell if Android thinks a wired headphone is currently connected?

By the way, I am running Cyanogenmod version 11-20141112-SNAPSHOT if that makes any difference.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that [stock Android seems to have a "headset icon" to indicate that a headset is connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/119298/18559), but apparently Cyanogenmod doesn't have this (or I accidentally disabled it somehow).

Comment: @Firelord: I edited my question. As I mentioned in [my other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/124491/18559), I can see that inserting the headset starts the audio player. What I am after here is a more "static" way to tell the status of the switch, as inserting/removing the headset might cause switch bouncing which could trigger the start of the app but doesn't guarantee that the state is correct when the headset isn't plugged in.

Comment: Have you been thorough(sic) with `/sys`, especially with `/sys/devices`? Is there anything relevant under `/proc/asound/`?

Comment: @Firelord: I don't know how to extract the headphone state from those resources - that would be exactly my question. I'll look into it more, one thing I found already is [dumpsys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11201659/897968) which I imagine could be useful..?